# How to determine how many times '0' to '9' have been used in a specific range instantly

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numbers

I want to count how many times '0' to '9' have been used in a specific range

e.g. 112 has two '1' and one '2'

Thanks for your advices, I changed my code now.

But it is not efficient as I want.

```
num = int(input('n : '))
start_time = time.time()
num_arr = [0] * 10
progress_arr = ['%d' % (num * (i / 100)) for i in range(1, 101)]

for i in range(1, num + 1):
    if str(i) in progress_arr:
        print(str(progress_arr.index(str(i)) + 1) + '%')
    for digit in str(i):
        num_arr[int(digit)] += 1

print('Time : %.2f' % (time.time() - start_time))
print(num_arr)
```

When I input 1000 as n, my program will print this arr instantly

[192, 301, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300]

It means for 1 to 1000,
'0' has been used 192 times and '1' has been used 301 times and ···

But when I input 2,000,000,000 as n, my program will print the result after 
11 minutes(Using pypy3, Ryzen 2600).

So I want to change my code as efficient to get the result of a very large number **instantly**.

And in my previous question, I mentioned the time complexity of O(N), which confused you because of my poor understanding of algorithm and time complexity. So I deleted it.

What I want to know is just the **efficient algorithm**.

I'm trying to find a specific rule by analyzing the difference in the results of increment, but it's not easy.

Comment: You need something like Digit Dynamic Programming. Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digit-dp-introduction/

Comment: Your program is far worse than O(n^2). Consider how many times you a) construct a stream representation of each distinct number and b) you then iterate over the entire string.

Comment: your code is already O(N), the problem is N is quite large

Comment: I changed my code now.

Comment: `get the result of 'n : 2 billion' instantly. N : the length of the input number (number of digits)` -- are you serious about getting results for 2billion digits instantly?

Comment: @lenik Yes my friend know that efficient algorithm. And I want to code that without check his code for my improvement.

But it is too hard for me, so I want some advices for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it!

```
def main():
    n = int(input('n : '))
    num_arr = [0] * 10
    w = 1

    for step in range(len(str(n))):
        remaining = 9 - int(str(n)[-1:])

        for i in range(len(num_arr)):
            num_arr[i] += (n // 10 + 1) * w

        for i in range(10 - remaining, 10):
            num_arr[i] -= w
        num_arr[0] -= w

        for number in str(n)[:-1]:
            num_arr[int(number)] -= remaining * w

        n //= 10
        w *= 10

    print(num_arr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now I cant get the result of 2 billion faster than 1 second! LOL

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem efficiently, you can't go through numbers one by one and count up their digits. You need to apply math.

---

Suppose the upper limit of the range is 123456. Let's try to figure out how many times each possible digit occurs in this range, in the hundreds place.

For every 1000 consecutive integers, each possible digit occurs 100 times in the hundreds place, except for when that digit would be a leading zero. There are 123456//1000=123 full 1000-integer chunks, with 123456%1000=456 integers from 123001 to 123456 left over. The full chunks give us 123*100=12300 occurrences of each digit in the hundreds place, minus 99 for digit 0 because of leading zeros.

In the range from 123001 to 123456, 0 appears 99 times in the hundreds place, each digit from 1 to 3 appears 100 times, and 4 appears 57 times.

---

Figure out how to formalize this logic enough to implement it in a program, and apply it to every digit place, and you'll easily be able to handle inputs much larger than 2 billion.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a way that will take about 30-40 minutes for an input of `2,000,000,000`, is that fast enough? Hopefully that's long before you are dead! It processes about 1,000,000 numbers per second on my machine. The key is that you are calling `count()` 10 times on each number, once for each digit. But if you just went through the number once and incremented based on what digit you see at each position, then you just run through each number once. My method also doesn't keep much in memory, so it won't run out of space (I chose to use a dict instead of a list of digits, but it should be about the same). My code:

```
num = 2 * (10**9) # 2 billion
num_dict = {}
for i in range(10):       # Dict to keep track of counts
    num_dict[str(i)] = 0

for i in range(1, num + 1):
    if i%1000000 == 0:           # print progress every Million
        print(f'Processed {i/1000000}M numbers')
    for digit in str(i):
        num_dict[digit] += 1

>>> print(num_dict)
{
    '0': 1688888898,
    '1': 2800000000,
    '2': 1800000001,
    '3': 1800000000,
    '4': 1800000000,
    '5': 1800000000,
    '6': 1800000000,
    '7': 1800000000,
    '8': 1800000000,
    '9': 1800000000
}
```

<s>I'll update with the answer in 40 minutes if you want</s>

Answer for `n : 2billion` is above! ;D

Happy Coding!

Comment: Now I can get the result of n : 2 billion but, What I want to know is an algorithm that's efficient enough to get the result of 2 billion instantly. 

But thanks to your solution, the efficiency of my code has improved a lot.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh, you're question says you want an O(N) instead of your current O(N^2), so that's what I solved. Ah, you want a tricky way to shortcut and get the answer instantly! That'll take some analysis of how the counts increment, if I have time I'll answer again, but for now this will have to do.  Answer for n : 2 billion is above!

Comment: This algo is also O(n^2) if n is the number of digits instead of the numerical value of the input: `In [54]: %timeit sam(10) - 8.14 µs ; In [55]: %timeit sam(100) - 
57 µs ; In [56]: %timeit sam(1000) - 689 µs`. And it's about the same speed as the faster version (2) of my algo above.

Comment: I worked out a way to get exact counts instantly, if you are summing up through a power of 10, check out my other answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I gave it a go at being even s-m-r-t'er. I took a look at the counts at a bunch of powers of 10:

```
At 10 totaldigits=11, counts are: [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
At 100 totaldigits=192, counts are: [11, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
At 1000 totaldigits=2893, counts are: [192, 301, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300]
At 10000 totaldigits=38894, counts are: [2893, 4001, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000]
At 100000 totaldigits=488895, counts are: [38894, 50001, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000]
At 1000000 totaldigits=5888896, counts are: [488895, 600001, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000]
At 10000000 totaldigits=68888897, counts are: [5888896, 7000001, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000]
```

A pattern has started to emerge! After `10^n` numbers, the counts for `2,3,...,9` are equal to `n * 10^(n-1)`, and the counts for `1` are 1 more than that, `n * 10^(n-1) + 1`. The counts for `0` are less than the others, and appear to be equal to the total digits at the previous power of ten! So, we can count the digits in the numbers through 10, and then for every power after that, the counts for 1 thru 9 can be computed directly, and the counts for 0 can be obtained from the previous total counts. i.e.:

```
total_digits_in = {}
total_digits_in[10] = 11
highest_power = 9
for cur_power in range(2, highest_power+1):
    counts = [
        total_digits_in[10**(cur_power-1)],     # zero = total counts at previous power of 10
        cur_power * (10**(cur_power - 1)) + 1,  # one = n * 10^(n-1) + 1
        cur_power * (10 ** (cur_power - 1)) ,   # 2 thru 9 = n * 10^(n-1)
        cur_power * (10 ** (cur_power - 1)),
        cur_power * (10 ** (cur_power - 1)),
        cur_power * (10 ** (cur_power - 1)),
        cur_power * (10 ** (cur_power - 1)),
        cur_power * (10 ** (cur_power - 1)),
        cur_power * (10 ** (cur_power - 1)),
        cur_power * (10 ** (cur_power - 1)),
    ]
    total_digits_in[10**cur_power] = sum(counts)
    print(f'Counts for 10^{cur_power}: {counts}')

Counts for 10^2: [11, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
Counts for 10^3: [192, 301, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300]
Counts for 10^4: [2893, 4001, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000]
Counts for 10^5: [38894, 50001, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000]
Counts for 10^6: [488895, 600001, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000]
Counts for 10^7: [5888896, 7000001, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000, 7000000]
Counts for 10^8: [68888897, 80000001, 80000000, 80000000, 80000000, 80000000, 80000000, 80000000, 80000000, 80000000]
Counts for 10^9: [788888898, 900000001, 900000000, 900000000, 900000000, 900000000, 900000000, 900000000, 900000000, 900000000]
```

This gets you the exact counts of each digit if going through the integers from 1 through a power of 10, essentially instantly. I think it will be significantly harder to get the counts for an arbitrary number between powers of 10. I don't think it's impossible, just ... difficult. Anyhow, hope you like this new solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrence of digits in each number in the range. And by maintaining the count as you loop through the range, you do it in one pass.

```
def digits(number):
    c = Counter()
    for n in range(1, number+1):
        c.update(str(n))

    # return [c[str(k)] for k in range(10)]
    return c
```

Output:

```
>>> digits(1000)
Counter({'1': 301, '2': 300, '3': 300, '4': 300, '5': 300, '6': 300, '7': 300, '8': 300, '9': 300, '0': 192})
```

And if you want it as a list of the digits counts from 0 to 9, then change the return line to:

```
return [c[str(k)] for k in range(10)]
```

```
>>> digits(1000)
[192, 301, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300]
```

As for complexity:

```
In [8]: %timeit digits(10)
16.8 µs ± 151 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit digits(100)
113 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit digits(1000)
1.14 ms ± 8.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For a 10x increase in the input value, there's a 10x increase in the time taken. That's O(n), not O(n^2).

If you're defining "n" *not as the input number* but as the *length of the input number* (number of digits), then yes, it's O(n^2). But that's an arbitrary decision on what "n" is. By that metric, all numerical algorithms which are currently O(n) would immediately become O(n^2). (I suppose defining the basis of 'n' is flexible.)

---

Here's a slightly version faster version of the same function, though having the same time complexity:

```
def digits(number):
    c = Counter(char for n in range(1, number+1) for char in str(n))
    return c  # or as one line
```

```
In [19]: %timeit digits(10)
7.15 µs ± 231 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit digits(100)
47.5 µs ± 1.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit digits(1000)
606 µs ± 48.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: collections.Counter() uses loops inside update therefore. it cant be claimed that it is O(n)

Comment: There is a correlation but I couldn't find it so far.

This code has  O(n^2) Time complexity too.

So I can't get the result of 'n : 2 billion'

Comment: Yes, the 'N' is the length of the input number (number of digits).

I am sorry for my indistinct explanation.

And what I want to know is an algorithm that's efficient enough to get the result of 2 billion.

But thank you for your consideration.

Comment: As per my comment on Sam's answer, both our solutions are O(n^2). I've noted the execution times for 10, 100 and 1000. Using the timing for number=1000 (606 µs). 2,000,000,000 will take approx `606 µs * 1,000,000 * 2 = 20.2 minutes`.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. I think my poor understanding of algorithm and time complexity confused you. So I deleted it. And now I am trying to find and formalize the specific rule which can get the result of a very large number. Thank you!